# Unclear time-to-frequency integration step

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution, wavelet

From [here](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Eingrid/publications/DM96.pdf); $\hat f=\mathcal{F}(f)$, bar = complex conjugate:

[image]

1. Time-shift property: $x(t-b) \Leftrightarrow e^{-j\omega b}{\bf X} (\omega)$, so why is it $+$ (red)?
2. What at all is happening? Looks like convolution theorem, taking $f$ and $\psi$'s time-domain multiplication into frequency domain, except don't we need a *second* integral for conv.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an application of [Parseval's (Plancherel's) Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel_theorem):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)g^*(t)dt=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(\omega)G^*(\omega)d\omega\tag{1}$$

where $F(\omega)$ and $G(\omega)$ are the Fourier transforms of $f(t)$ and $g(t)$, respectively. I've used $^*$ to denote complex conjugation.

Comment: Of course, your explanation is much more plausible than the one I posted. Though I came (almost) to the same conclusion, just in a more complicated manner. I will delete mine though as yours is more helpful.

Comment: Very fair, @Florian

Comment: @Florian: Your answer went in the right direction but using Parseval's theorem is probably more obvious.

Comment: What about the timeshift?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon: You need the complex conjugate, hence the positive sign.

Comment: As PT has many formulations of the same idea it'd help to include the derivation of the one you used, like [here](https://electricalvoice.com/parsevals-theorem-proof/) or [here](https://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~jdg/eeft3.pdf); Wikipedia relates a time-domain integer-sum to a frequency-domain integral over a period, rather than continuous-infinte sum (integral) to continuous-infinte sum.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon: I've changed the link, because the wikipedia article on Parseval's theorem indeed doesn't mention Eq. (1) of my answer. In mathematics, that formula is more often called Plancherel theorem, whereas in signal processing we usually call it (generalized) Parseval's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Matt isn't wrong, but there's a more satisfactory answer; it *is* convolution theorem:

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)\psi^*(t-b)dt 
 &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(\omega) \Psi^*(\omega) e^{j\omega b}d\omega \\
 &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \mathcal{F}^{-1}( F(\omega) \Psi^*(\omega) )
\end{align}
$$

and the $+b$ timeshift is per the complex conjugate. Note that without the $b$ in $\psi()$, Parseval / Plancherel's theorem is more directly applicable, so here they're equivalent, but not necessarily with same assumptions/interpretations. Convolution is 'correct' in context, and enables $\text{FFT}$.